# Merge private attributes in Python

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-class

I know that private attributes are loosely defined in Python, but I'm trying to figure out what would be the most lean way of implementing a method to merge together private attributes.

```
Class Event:
  target_time: datetime
  _names: set
```

I'm thinking of having a static method to merge together two Events.

```
@staticmethod
def merge(event1: Event, event2: Event) -> Event:
  new_event = Event()
  new_event._names = event1._names + event2._names
  return new_event
```

But I'm unsure if this breaks some good design patterns about private attribute since they are private.

Comment: If `merge` is a method on `Event`, then this is totally fine.

Comment: So something like this ?
```
def merge(self, other_event: Event) -> Event:
   new_event = Event()
   new_event = self._names + other_event._names
  return new_event
```

Comment: Yes, but also as a static method as shown in the question is fine too. (Except that `new_event = Event()` in both your examples appears to be superfluous?!) What concern do you have about the above code?

Comment: Since it's within a static method, it seems to mean that I'm accessing internal attributes of an object which I maybe should avoid ?

Comment: The method is part of the class that defines the attribute. The class is expected to know how to treat those protected attributes correctly. It isn't limited to only accessing that attribute on `self`.

Comment: Got it thanks, I will go with that then!

Answer (score 0):

##### Errors in code

```py
1. @staticmethod
2. def merge(event1: Event, event2: Event) -> Event:
3.   new_event = Event()
4.   new_event = event1._names + event2._names
5.  return new_event
```

- `new_event` in lines 3 and 4 are different types, `Event` and `set` respectively.
- `new_event` in line 5 doesn't match with declared return-type.

##### Suggestion

Use Python data model. Create new `Event` using syntax
`new_event = event1 + event2` by implementing `__add__` method.

##### Suggested Implementation

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Event:
    target_time: datetime
    _names: set

    def __init__(self, target_time: datetime, names: set):
        self.target_time = target_time
        self._names = names
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        # set new time as you like
        new_time = self.target_time if self.target_time > other.target_time else other.target_time
        new_event = Event(
            new_time,
            self._names | other._names
            )
        return new_event

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self._names} @ {self.target_time}\n"
```

Now you can merge `Event`s like this:

```py
tonight = datetime.today().replace(hour=21, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
tomor_night = tonight+timedelta(hours=24)
yest_night =  tonight+timedelta(hours=-24)

event1 = Event(tonight, {"Get", "Set", "Go"})
event2 = Event(tomor_night, {"Get", "Set", "Again"})
event3 = Event(yest_night, {"Got" "It"})

new_event = event1 + event2 + event3

print(event1, event2, event3, new_event)
```

output:

```bash
{'Set', 'Go', 'Get'} @ 2023-07-07 21:00:00
{'Set', 'Again', 'Get'} @ 2023-07-08 21:00:00
{'GotIt'} @ 2023-07-06 21:00:00
{'GotIt', 'Go', 'Set', 'Again', 'Get'} @ 2023-07-08 21:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks for flagging this, just an oversight in my example code to explain my question about design patterns, not really about the merge itself.